# redirect https://www to https:// through web.config

Tags: iis, web, web-config, redirect

I want to redirect anything to https://domain.com
I found this code:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="SecureRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

And its working except on https://www.domain.com
My virtual server is Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8, and the domain is https://kajsystem.com

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using IIS 8 configurations including using the URL Rewrite module, which can handle forwarding and retain the entire requested URL. There is a fairly comprehensive article on MSDN site covering this:

[MSDN redirect on IIS 7 and higher](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx)